# How to make Tkinter create_text print 'string' keys (such as letters and numbers) and not key names (such as 'tab')

Tags: python, string, tkinter

I am trying to make my own text editor (something like MS Word, but infinetely more simple) and I am in the early stages of my project. I am using Tkinter to create my GUI and the following prints keys to the canvas after they are pressed:

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.i = StringVar(master, '0')
        self.master = master
        self.mouseClick = None
        ...
        master.bind("<Any KeyPress>", lambda event: self.drawText(event.keysym))

    def clicked(self, event):
        if self.mouseClick is None:
            self.mouseClick = event

    def drawText(self, key):
        if self.mouseClick is not None:
            if key not in keys:
                self.canva1.create_text(self.mouseClick.x, self.mouseClick.y, text=key)
            self.mouseClick.x += 6

master = Tk()
GUI(master)
master.mainloop()
```

The problem with this code is that when I press on 'non-string' keys the name of the key gets printed. For example, pressing backspace will print 'backSpace'

I tried creating a list named key that contains the name of the keys I don't want to print, and then using an if statement in the drawText function like this:

```
 def drawText(self, key):
        keys = ['Return', 'Enter', 'BackSpace', 'space', 'Control_L', 'Tab', 'Up', 'Down', 'Right', 'Left',
                'Alt_R,', 'Alt_L', 'F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5', 'F6', 'F7', 'F8', 'F9', 'F10', 'F11', 'F12', 'Insert',
                'Delete', 'grave', 'Next', 'Prior', 'Escape', 'comma', 'Win_L', 'Win_R', 'Alt_R', 'Num_Lock', 'End',
                'Caps_Lock', 'Shift_L', 'Shift_R', 'period', 'semicolon', 'minus', 'equal', 'slash', 'asterisk',
                'plus', 'bracketleft', 'bracketright', 'backslash', 'apostrophe', 'exclam', 'at', 'numbersign',
                'dollar', 'percent', 'asciicircum', 'ampersand']
        if self.mouseClick is not None:
            if key not in keys:
                self.canva1.create_text(self.mouseClick.x, self.mouseClick.y, text=key)
        self.mouseClick.x += 6
```

This approach works as those keys don't get printed when I press them, but I feel manually entering every key name in the list is highly inefficient. I was wondering if there is another way I am unaware of that will let me skip those keys so I only print letters and numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want nothing if it's a special key you can just use the `Event.char` property. It'll be empty for all special keys and as an example apostrophe would give `'`.

Comment: No, `Event.char` is not empty for `tab` key for example.